# Where is the CoreSimulator directory in Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, watchos-simulator, tvos-simulator, visionos-simulator

Xcode 15 do not has built-in platforms and need extra download to somewhere

Do not exist at somewhere like `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot`

Answer (score 2):

It's at `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/*.dmg`.

If you have multiple dmgs, the `images.plist` file will indicate which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Saafo’s question and answer:

---

In order to mount the `iOS`, `watchOS`, `tvOS`, or `visionOS` simulator disk images from `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images`, you need to copy them to `Desktop` for example, otherwise you’ll get “permission denied” error.

Once you mount any of the copied disk images, open the volume and on it:

1. Go to `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/PLATFORM XX.X.simruntime`
2. Right-click on `.simruntime` file and select `Show Package Contents`
3. In newly opened folder, go to
   `Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot`

Now you have access to simulator root directory.